# Windows 10 location is unavailable error for files created using ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, windows-10

I am trying to access this location `F:\ASU Fall 16\Conginitive Sc\week 2: Perception and Psychophysics` on my Windows 10 system and it is giving me the following error:
[image]

I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot mode. I might have created this folder when I was using ubuntu, but I have created a number of other folder which I created in ubuntu and I am able to access in my Win10

Comment: While NTFS and Windows support colon characters in path names (if they're running in POSIX-compliant mode), most Windows software doesn't like them (because they clash with drive name delimiters). Some file managers can operate in POSIX mode and access (and rename) them but Windows Explorer is not among them. In any case, this is a Windows question and off topic here.

Comment: I've added the question here, since there is no askWindows.com

Comment: @vipin8169 But there is http://superuser.com/.

Comment: but i guess it was related to ubuntu, since i created those files using ubuntu only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What part of the path is there? Did you check? Maybe the colon? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename)